# What is the definition of a pattern in Rust and what is pattern matching?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, rust

I am a programmer who is very familiar with languages like C and C++, but I have very little experience with things that are functional in nature. I am attempting to learn Rust and would like to know what Rust defines a pattern as, and what pattern matching with a `match` expression is in Rust.

Comment: [The book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html) explains just that

Comment: The book was my goto source, it didn't compute for me at all. I am misunderstanding it and it's not very in depth for my reasoning.

Comment: @TheRenegade you should open an issue for the book. If you don't understand it and can explain what's wrong, then the book itself can be improved and **everyone benefits**.

Comment: @Shepmaster That was my plan, I will see what I can do.

Comment: @martijn-pieters How is this too broad? It simply asks what patterns are and how they are matched?

Comment: @TheRenegade: Yes, and that's too broad a list. As the accepted answer notes: *Many types of patterns exist in Rust*.

Comment: @martijn-pieters Not what my question entailed. It asked what all of those patterns where defined as, not a list, and what pattern matching is as well. It's like asking what a variable is, I don't need the entire list of strings, chars, ints etc. After consulting Apple's docs i finally found patterns defined as a sort of structure. All I needed to know. The person here happend to answer my question as well. Why I selected that and the only answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many types of patterns exist in Rust. The most notable ones are:

- Literals, such as `42`. These match the given value. So if you do `match f() {42 => ...}`, the 42 case will be entered if `f()` returned 42.
- Identifiers, such as `x`. This matches anything and assigns the matched value to `x`. So in the following code:

  ```
  match f() {
    42 => println!("Correct!"),
    x => println!("{} is the wrong answer", x)
  }
  ```

  "Correct!" will be printed if `f()` returned 42 and otherwise the entered number will be printed with " is the wrong answer" after it.
- The wildcard pattern `_`. Like an identifier, this matches anything, but unlike an identifier nothing is assigned. Use this if you don't need the matched value (say you wouldn't want to print the entered number in the above example, then you could just write `_ => println!("Wrong")`
- For any variant `X(arg1, ..., argN)` of an enum, `X(pattern1, ..., patternN)` is a valid pattern and for any variant `Y` without arguments, `Y` is a valid pattern. The pattern `Y` matches the variant `Y`. The pattern `X(pattern1, ..., patternN)` matches an instance of the variant `X` if its argument match patterns `pattern1` through `patternN` respectively. Consider this example:

  ```
  enum Foo {
    X(i32, i32),
    Y
  }

  fn g() -> Foo { ... }

  fn foo() {
    match g() {
      X(a,b) -> a+b
      Y -> 0
    }
  }
  ```

  Here foo() will return the sum of the X's values if `g()` returned an `X` or it will return 0 if `g()` returned `Y`.

Comment: Useful links: [Match](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/match.html) and [Patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html) in the book and [match expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions) in the reference. Other important patterns include tuples, pattern joining with "|", ranges, subpatterns with "@". Enum variants may have `X`, `X( .. )` or `X{ .. }` syntax depending on how they were declared.